# Eigenvalues of bordered non-symmetric matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Is it possible to express the eigenvalues of $M$:
$$M=\begin{bmatrix}
A_{n \times n} & -B_{n \times m} \\ B^T_{m \times n} & 0_{m \times m}
\end{bmatrix},$$ in terms of the sub-matrix eigenvalues? Could you please provide some hints or references?

Thank you in advance.

PS: $A$ is positive definite, and $B$ has independent columns.

Comment: Is $A$ itself skew symmetric or not ?

Comment: Thanks for the interest, $A$ can be a symmetric positive semi-definite matrix and $rank(B)=m$.

Comment: I am puzzled by your "$A$ can be...". In mathematics, it is ... or it is not (in this case $A$ is "general", not especialy skew-symmetric or symmetric...)

Comment: Sorry, $A$ is symmetric positive semi-definite.

Comment: Maybe you get some feed if you remove the skew symmetric since $A\ge 0$ and replace finding by bounding the maximum eigenvalue. I guess.

Comment: Using Schur complement, it can be shown that $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $M$ if and only if $\lambda$ is a nonzero root of $\det\left(\lambda^2 I_n-\lambda A-BB^T\right)=0$. Unless $A$ commutes with $BB^T$, I don't see any way to express $\lambda$ in terms of the eigenvalues of $A$ and $BB^T$.

Comment: @user1551 thanks for the response. I am trying to reproduce your result. Did you applied the formula
$\begin{align}
  \begin{bmatrix} A & B \\ C & D \end{bmatrix} &=
  \begin{bmatrix} I_p & BD^{-1} \\ 0 & I_q \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} A - BD^{-1}C & 0 \\ 0 & D \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} I_p & 0 \\ D^{-1}C & I_q \end{bmatrix},
\end{align}$ on   $M - \lambda I$?